# set image resource drawable with a programmatic String

Tags: android, resources, drawable, identifier

Using an array with a base adapter to populate a listview. There are over many optional drawables and so a switch case is highly inefficient. I've been trying to implement a two liner using getResources().getIdentifier() system but all attempts have failed returning resource id of 0 x 0000.

working code

```
            try {
                final ImageView star = convertView.findViewById(R.id.star);
                final JSONObject object = list.getJSONObject(i);
                switch (object.getString("star")){
                    case "a":
                        star.setImageResource(R.drawable.stara);
                        break;
                    case "b":
                        star.setImageResource(R.drawable.starb);
                        break;
                    case "c":
                        star.setImageResource(R.drawable.starc);
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        star.setImageResource(R.drawable.stard);
                        break;
                }
```

I'm needing something using something like this but getIdentifier() method

```
final ImageView star = convertView.findViewById(R.id.star);
star.setImageDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("star" + object.getString("star") + ".png", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName())));
```

"star" + object.getString("star") + ".png" is the exact drawable name in resource folder (stara.png, starb.png, ....)

I keep getting this exception with getIdentifier() method

```
No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
```

How to properly implement this or a better way using a programmatic string to determine the resource drawable name being set to an imageview?

Comment: Remove `+ ".png"`. You don't specify the extension for resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be omitting the ".png". If you are looking for "stara.png", what you are trying to get is the idenfifier `R.drawable.stara`, so what you should have is

```
getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("star" + object.getString("star"), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName())));
```

Comment: Thank You! Will be accepted answer in 9 mins. Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: Well if you really need to map from a value in your `JSONObject` like "a" to a drawable, I can't think of any other options besides the switch and using  `getIdentifier`. What I can suggest, however, is not dealing with a `JSONObject` directly. Use your `List<JSONObject>` to create a `List<YourModelObject>` and that should be what you use with your adapter. For each model object you only need to do the conversion from string to drawable ID once (in the constructor) and then you can just return the ID with something like `public int getDrawableId()`. That will be more efficient in the end.

Comment: You could also just simply use a static Map to resolve your drawable integers from the keys provided by the JSONObject.